# How to make this intersection chart?

Tags: visualization

I want to prepare the following chart. Say, I have three datasets of different lengths, for example:

```
A = [c,d,e,g,h,o,m,n,o,x,y,z]
B = [d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]
C = [a,b,c,d,e]
```

Any dataset might contain items already there in other 2 datasets. Now I want to show the size of each dataset as a circle. More items, bigger circle. But all three circles also overlap each other depending on how much items are common. As demonstrated below.

[image]

What this chart is actually called? And what library can I use which might have this kind of chart available?

Comment: What language? It‘s a Venn diagram https://python-graph-gallery.com/venn-diagram/

Comment: Javascript. But you made it. It's here: https://www.benfrederickson.com/venn-diagrams-with-d3.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Peter. It's called Venn Diagram and here's my needed Javascript Library. https://www.benfrederickson.com/venn-diagrams-with-d3.js/